# ImageMagick converting pdf to images, converted page count

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick

i want to learn how many pages will be converted with ImageMagick command.

```
convert -density 150 -quality 100 -resize 800x "new.pdf" "pdtoimg.jpg"
```

It returns 6 pages with name of `pdtoimg-0.jpg` to `pdtoimg-5.jpg`.

is there any way to learn how many pages are in a pdf, or can I make it write the converted page names to an array?

If I want to take folder size, I have to wait all processing has ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `identify`. This is also one of the ImageMagick commands.

```
identify file.pdf
identify -format "%f: %n\n" file.pdf
```

But for PDFs, this can be **quite slow** (because ImageMagick needs to use Ghostscript as a *delegate* for PDF processing, and Ghostscript needs to do a complete interpretation of the PDF before IM will be able to spit out the info you are interested in).

So **much faster** would be to use an external tool, which does not read in the complete PDF, but only evaluates its metadata object:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep Pages:
pdfinfo file.pdf | grep Pages: | awk '{print $2}'
```

`pdfinfo` is a tool available as part of the XPDF package or as part of the Poppler utilities (both available for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows).